# Nested Logic Apps in Azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Question about implementing nested Logic Apps in Azure: I do know Logic Apps currently doesn't support variables. Looking for other options.

I would like to pass the values back and forth between logic apps - I have seen a couple of articles on how to implement nested logic but they are not bidirectional. My challenge is to process the body that's coming from the child logic app and pass it over to another logic app as input. It's something like this I wanted to try.

ParentLogicApp:foreach(ActionName)

ParentLogicApp:Assign the Body to a variable(place holder)

ParentLogicApp:Call Specific ActionValue LogicApp

```
        ChildLogicApp:In this logic app do the corresponding Action
        ChildLogicApp:Return the updated Body to the parent logic app
```

ParentLogicApp:Update the Variable with the new value from Child

PartnerLogicApp:Call the next step child logic app passing the updated variable

I have tried to use Compose but was not able to update the value from the child logic app. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If your child logic app has a Response step, then the output of the invoke child logic app step in your parent logic app will be the response that the child logic app produced (note that internally invoked logic apps are not subject to any response timeouts). Output of one child logic app can then be passed in as input to the next child logic app, so you would not need variables for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To have a variable that's accessible from multiple logic apps, consider store it in DocDB and use DocDB connector to CRUD it.

Comment: Yup, finally ended up using a DB to store the temp values. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data back-and-forth between logic apps, that is what body is for.
When calling a logic app, just put it in the request body for the call, then you can return whatever data back from that logic app in its response body.

For your scenario, you can definitely use variables and set them to a value you received from a logic app call, and use the new value to pass to a next logic app.